# Selecting Random value from Excel column data using vbscript NOT working

Tags: excel, vbscript, hp-uft

Here is my code below. I'm trying to select a random value from one column of excel sheet. there are 30 rows in one column and i need select random value each time during execution.

```
    strFullExcelPath="C:\POS_AUTOMATION\POS_Item_Details\POS_Data.xls"
    Sheet1Name="GCNumber"


    Set objAdodbCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    objAdodbCon.Provider = "MSDASQL"
    objAdodbCon.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};" & _
            "DBQ=" & strFullExcelPath & ";Readonly=True"

    objAdodbCon.Open



    Set objAdodbRecSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    objAdodbRecSet.CursorLocation=3

    strSQLStatement =  "SELECT * from [" & Sheet1Name & "$]"

    objAdodbRecSet.Open strSQLStatement, objAdodbCon


    RowCount = objAdodbRecSet.RecordCount

    Min = 1 : Max = RowCount

    Randomize
    GC_Numbers = Int(((Max - Min) * Rnd) + Min)
```

I am trying to use below line to get the value of column. But not working to get what i want. Please suggest.

```
    objAdodbRecSet.fields(GC_Numbers)
```

Comment: Please define "not working" - what are you getting back?  What are you expecting to get back?

Comment: I'm trying to get a random value from a column in excel sheet. I'm getting error at the last line of script objAdodbRecSet.fields(GC_Numbers).

Comment: What error are you getting?